# Mysterious Underlines in ALL Browsers on macOS

Tags: macos, catalina

I run an old web application that still works perfectly (PHP/MySQL) and if I use a macOS Catalina, characters with a following underscore are displayed like this:

[image]

The source code looks perfect:

```
<select onchange="checkField(this.name);" size="20" name="auf_id" id="choose_task">
  <option value="1196">[1196] AB_Angela_Kreis Forch_an_Kinder Meier: 19.12.2019</option>
  ... (more <option>) ...
 </select>
```

This happens on two Macs, and in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. On Windows, the text renders normally.

I don't understand why and don't know how to even search on the internet about that.

Comment: I have never seen this particular example, but it looks like possibly a old Apple font being used where certain characters get automatically combined with the preceding letter to form an "accented" character.

Comment: Wow thanks Tom. It was definitely a font issue. The site uses a font from Google. If I set it to Helvetica, it looks normal. Thank you!